# How to add dynamic data to multiple table in sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am creating generic web application, that will generate interface fields from DB, I can get and pass value to DB from those fields since fields are dynamic I pass those value to DB as a string with comma separated as shown below,

```
'MemberID:M001,FirstName:Kasun,LastName:Harshana,CompanyName:cmp'
```

it contains field id and the user insert value for the field

> eg: MemberID = M001

But my problem is how to get value from dynamic fields and insert those into multiple tables 
eg: MemberId and FirstName should insert into Member Table and FirstName, LastName, and CompanyName should insert to the Person Table

these tables depend on the input string to the procedure, that string can have more than one table and it depends on the field of my view `('MemberID:M001,FirstName:Kasun,LastName:Harshana,CompanyName:cmp') : 2 table`

for more details, I here attach sample table structure with this,[this is the table where I get fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsdlE.png)
[this the table where contains  field belong table detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FleUW.png)

I need to create a stored procedure in SQL server to add these into particular tables 
any approach to achieve this will be warmly welcome,

thanks

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? You should write you own code and ask questions when you get stuck. I would advise to not send this kind of csv files to a stored procedure, but handle this in you C# code.

Comment: Are you having trouble writing the web API or the stored procedure? Having such a generic interface via a web api is security issue.

Answer (score 0):

When the event runs for the data entry, you should call two stored procedures on the database:
create proc usp_MemberTable
@pMemberID,
@pLastName
as
insert into membertable
values
(@pMemberID,@pLastName)

create proc usp_PesronTable
--parameters as colums
as
--sql statement with the parameters.

For the person table I would add member ID as a foreign key.
Parameters can be passed from the data entry objects of the form in c#.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[usp_CreateMemberByString](@Input 
nvarchar(max),@KeyUser bigint,@KeySession int = 0 , @KeyClient bigint 
=0,@retVal INT OUTPUT,@retMsg varchar(500) output)
AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @KeyMember bigint,@keyHousehold bigint,@MemberID 
    varchar(30),@FirstName varchar(50),@LastName varchar(50),@MiddleInitial 
    varchar(1),@NamePrefix varchar(20),@NameSuffix varchar(20)
       ,@Title int,@CompanyName varchar(50),@Status bit,@EnrollDate 
    datetime,@IsMainMember bit,@HomePhone varchar(20),@MobilePhone 
    varchar(20),@WorkPhone varchar(20),@DateofBirth datetime
       ,@Gender varchar(10),@EmailAddress varchar(100),@Notes 
    varchar(2000),@Source varchar(20)
       ,@Address1 varchar(45),@Address2 varchar(45),@City 
    varchar(30),@StateProvince varchar(50),@CountryCode 
    varchar(10),@StreetNumber varchar(10),@PostalCode varchar(10)
       ,@SendEmail bit,@SendMail bit,@SendText bit
       ,@EnteredBy varchar(20)
       ,@imgPath varchar(500) = ''

DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT,@Character char = ','
SET @StartIndex = 1

IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
BEGIN
      SET @Input = @Input + @Character
END

WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
BEGIN
      SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

      --Start sperate item name and vakue
      DECLARE @SubStartIndex INT, @SubEndIndex INT,@SubCharacter char = ':',@SubInput NVARCHAR(250)
      SET @SubStartIndex = 1
      SET @SubInput = SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

      SET @SubEndIndex = CHARINDEX(@SubCharacter, @SubInput)

      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'MemberID')
      Begin
         set @MemberID = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'FirstName')
      Begin
         set @FirstName = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'LastName')
      Begin
         set @LastName = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'MiddleInitial')
      Begin
         set @MiddleInitial = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'NamePrefix')
      Begin
         set @NamePrefix = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'NameSuffix')
      Begin
         set @NameSuffix = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'Title')
      Begin
         set @Title = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'CompanyName')
      Begin
         set @CompanyName = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'Status')
      Begin
         set @Status = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'EnrollDate')
      Begin
         set @EnrollDate = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'IsMainMember')
      Begin
         set @IsMainMember = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'HomePhone')
      Begin
         set @HomePhone = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'MobilePhone')
      Begin
         set @MobilePhone = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'WorkPhone')
      Begin
         set @WorkPhone = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'DateofBirth')
      Begin
         set @DateofBirth = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'Gender')
      Begin
         set @Gender = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'EmailAddress')
      Begin
         set @EmailAddress = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'Notes')
      Begin
         set @Notes = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'Source')
      Begin
         set @Source = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'Address1')
      Begin
         set @Address1 = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'Address2')
      Begin
         set @Address2 = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'City')
      Begin
         set @City = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'StateProvince')
      Begin
         set @StateProvince = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'CountryCode')
      Begin
         set @CountryCode = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'StreetNumber')
      Begin
         set @StreetNumber = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'PostalCode')
      Begin
         set @PostalCode = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'SendEmail')
      Begin
         set @SendEmail = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'SendMail')
      Begin
         set @SendMail = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'SendText')
      Begin
         set @SendText = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
      if(SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubStartIndex, @SubEndIndex - 1) = 'KeyMember')
      Begin
         set @KeyMember = SUBSTRING(@SubInput, @SubEndIndex + 1, LEN(@SubInput));
      end
     --End sperate item name and vakue

     SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
END
if(@KeyMember != 0)
begin
    exec usp_UpdateMember 0,@KeyMember,0,@MemberID,@FirstName,@LastName,@MiddleInitial,@NamePrefix,@NameSuffix,@Title,@CompanyName,@Status
       ,@EnrollDate,@IsMainMember,@HomePhone,@MobilePhone,@WorkPhone,@DateofBirth,@Gender,@EmailAddress,@Notes,@Source,@EnteredBy
       ,@Address1,@Address2,@City,@StateProvince,@CountryCode,@StreetNumber,@PostalCode,@SendEmail,@SendMail,@SendText,@EnteredBy,''                                    
       ,@retVal output,@retMsg output;
end

else
begin
    exec usp_CreateMember @KeyUser,@keyHousehold,@MemberID,@FirstName,@LastName,@MiddleInitial,@NamePrefix,@NameSuffix,@Title,@CompanyName,@Status,@EnrollDate,@IsMainMember
       ,@HomePhone,@MobilePhone,@WorkPhone,@DateofBirth,@Gender,@EmailAddress,@Notes,@Source,@Address1,@Address2,@City,@StateProvince,@CountryCode,@StreetNumber,@PostalCode
       ,@SendEmail,@SendMail,@SendText,@EnteredBy,@imgPath,@KeySession,@KeyClient,@retVal output,@retMsg output;
end
```

END

this is the procedure that i have created,but here only added to static table i want do it dynamically,

Comment: exec usp_CreateMemberByString 'MemberID:M001,FirstName:Kasun,LastName:Harshana,CompanyName:cmp,EnrollDate:1970/01/01,MobilePhone:0112236987,DateofBirth:1970/01/01,Gender:Male,EmailAddress:Email@test.com,Address1:Horana,KeyMember:104367',1,1,1,1,'msg'